# Find out mapped property using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, exception, automapper

I'm looking to 'map' errors when persisting DTOs back to the property in a viewmodel corresponding to the DTO property that caused the error, `PersonDto.PreferedName` causes a DB error, say `Cannot be null`, and this property maps to the viemodel `PersonViewModel.Name`, I want to be able to display an error message in the langiage of the view, e.g. "Name is required".

Is there any way I can query `Mapper` or some other AutoMapper object to find which viewmodel property `PreferedName` maps to?

Comment: Why not annotate your view model with `[Required]`? Your data should be validated way before it touches the database and database errors logged for inspection.

Comment: @ChrisPickford It's a client/server app, and the data gets saved using a Web API, and captured in a WPF windows app and WPF doesn't recognise data annotations such as `Required`, Thanks, remembered the missing `WPF` tag.

Comment: You could still do it and check for `ModelState.IsValid` in your WebAPI controllers. Could even serialize and return `ModelState.Values` to your WPF front end for display to the user.

Comment: Ah, yes, @ChrisPickford. I am now returning an `ApiResponse` object from all API actions, and that has a collection of model errors derived from `ModelState`. Make you comment an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper in the WPF or WebAPI project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the errors from the ModelState but to answer the original question you can use the following

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplicationAutoMapper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
                                                        .ForMember(dest => dest.DtoMyProperty, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.MyProperty)
                                                          ));

            Order order = new Order() { MyProperty = 12 };

            var typeMaps = config.CreateMapper()
                                 .ConfigurationProvider
                                 .GetAllTypeMaps()
                                 .Where(t => t.SourceType == typeof(Order) && t.DestinationType == typeof(OrderDto))
                                 .Single()
                                 .GetPropertyMaps();

            foreach (var map in typeMaps)
                Console.WriteLine(map.SourceMember.Name + "->" + map.DestinationProperty.Name);



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDto
    {
        public int DtoMyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No0. I no0t getting the errors from the `ModelState`. I am getting them from the `DbEntityValidationException.EntityValidationErrors` property, but thanks, your code looks like it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, you can annotate your viewmodel with `[Required]` ([System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) and check in your controller action for `ModelState.IsValid`.

Serializing the contents of `ModelState.Values` and returning to your WPF front end will allow you to display any validation errors in whatever way suits.

Comment: My design for the API is to keep it pure and deal only with DTOs, i.e. low down entity models, and while I have e.g. some props in them set as required in fluent code-first, those validations are only done at `SaveChanges`, and come back as an exception with validation errors on the DTO properties. This is so the API is usable by any app, no matter what types its viewmodels are. When a client app receives back a DTO property error, I'd like to map it back to that clients viewmodel property for reporting in the UI.

Comment: I'm not sure we share the same definition of DTO (Data Transfer Object). They are typically synonymous with WebAPI viewmodels. Either way, you can still annotate your entity models if that's what your controller methods are communicating with and the above still applies.

Comment: Even if I annotate the entity models, I still want to find out what viewmodel properties they map to, so I can present errors to the user with property names they will understand.